# How do I sort a large number of security vulnerabilities (CVEs) by severity?

Tags: cve

During the course of my work, I was enumerating about 14 IPs and now my next task is manual checking each of the 500+ CVEs I found. I would like to sort them by severity and automate this as much as possible. Are there any tools that would help me?

Comment: It would be very helpful to know how you were finding the CVEs and why the tool/report you used can't simply be sorted. What you've asked is "I have data how do I sort it?" which really isn't a security question. What have you got, how did you get it?